# Delete User Custom Action

Tags: 2010, javascript, custom-actions

I wanted to add an action button in the Site Actions menu and I found a code easy to incorporate :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', AddCustomUserAction);  
});  

function AddCustomUserAction() {  
    //Get the client context and web object   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();  
    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();  
    //Get the custom user action collection and add the new custom action to it   
    var collUserCustomAction = oWeb.get_userCustomActions();  
    var oUserCustomAction = collUserCustomAction.add();  
    //Specify the location and properties for the new custom action   
    oUserCustomAction.set_location('Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu');  
    oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(101);  
    oUserCustomAction.set_group('SiteActions');  
    oUserCustomAction.set_title("New Action Item");  
    oUserCustomAction.set_url("/site/linksite.html");  
    oUserCustomAction.update();  
    //Load the client context and execute the batch   
    clientContext.load(collUserCustomAction);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
}
```

from [Priyaranjan K S](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sharepoint-custom-user-action-in-site-actions-menu-using-javascript-objec/) . Except putting the code in Site Asset, it put it in Style Library. Afterwards, I tried to modify the title, but it duplicated... I deleted the content editor web part containing the code but all the duplicated are still in my Site Actions menu..

I tried the code and changee ".add" but ".delete" or ".deleteobject" and a few codes from the internet without success... Can someone please help me? I am not sure where went wrong... Maybe I should have include the code in a content editor web part from the same page as where I put the "addcustomaction" even though I deleted it already?
I am using SharePoint 2010 and i am really limited in usage.

Here is one of those I tried :

```
function deleteUserCustomAction() {
this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
this.collUserCustomAction = oWebsite.get_userCustomActions();
clientContext.load(oWebsite,'UserCustomActions','Title');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.deleteCustomAction), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));}
}
function deleteCustomAction() {
var customActionEnumerator = collUserCustomAction.getEnumerator();
while (customActionEnumerator.moveNext())  {
  var oUserCustomAction = customActionEnumerator.get_current();
  if (oUserCustomAction.get_title() == 'New Menu Item') {
       oUserCustomAction.deleteObject();        
       clientContext.load(oUserCustomAction);
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
```

from [Kodono](https://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2014/06/12/delete-a-user-custom-action-from-sharepoint-javascript/)

Answer (score 3):

You must not just copy/paste the code [from my blog](https://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2014/06/12/delete-a-user-custom-action-from-sharepoint-javascript/), but you must customize it for your case.

This code is for [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408647%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so you have to adapt it to you.

I think it should result with something like:

```
function deleteUserCustomAction() {
  this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
  this.collUserCustomAction = oWebsite.get_userCustomActions();
  clientContext.load(oWebsite,'UserCustomActions','Title');
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.deleteCustomAction), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function deleteCustomAction() {
  var customActionEnumerator = collUserCustomAction.getEnumerator();
  while (customActionEnumerator.moveNext())  {
    var oUserCustomAction = customActionEnumerator.get_current();
    if (oUserCustomAction.get_title() == 'New Action Item') {
         oUserCustomAction.deleteObject();        
         clientContext.load(oUserCustomAction);
         clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
      }
  }
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
  alert('Custom action removed');
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
deleteUserCustomAction()
```

I've just replaced `'New Menu Item'` by `'New Action Item'` because you have `oUserCustomAction.set_title("New Action Item");` in your code.

Comment: Hello @AymKdn , first of all, thank you for your quick reply.  I am sorry, that I copied your whole code. When I added the code, i had a problem and when I re-added it, I forgot to modify it to "New Action"...
I tried your code again and it doesn't work :( You think maybe there is something I am missing? I copied your code in a .js then I added the file in a Content Editor WebPart...

Comment: Try to copy/paste it directly into the web console of your browser, and look at what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, helped for my:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var _clientContext, _userCustomActions;
function modifyUserCustomAction() {
    var web;
    _clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    web = _clientContext.get_web();
    _userCustomActions = web.get_userCustomActions();
    _clientContext.load(_userCustomActions);
    _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, deleteCustomAction), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}
function deleteCustomAction() {
    var customActionEnumerator = _userCustomActions.getEnumerator();
    var customAction;
    while (customActionEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var userCustomAction = customActionEnumerator.get_current();
        // Change only PopulateCustomIdScript
        if (userCustomAction.get_title() === 'PopulateCustomIdScript')
        {
            customAction = userCustomAction;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(customAction){
        customAction.deleteObject();
        _clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceededOnDeleting), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailedOnDeleting));
    }
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('onQueryFailed');
}
function onQuerySucceededOnDeleting() {
    alert('Succeeded');
}
function onQueryFailedOnDeleting(sender, args) {
    alert('onQueryFailedFromDeleting');
}
modifyUserCustomAction();
})();
```